# Looking for code to render a form that displays a view of an object

Tags: asp.net, controls, propertygrid

I've got the task of displaying a web form to represent the properties in a .NET class.  In WinForms, there's a pre-fab control named PropertyGrid that is a lot like what I need.  I'm just looking for something to display a simple layout of property names next to an appropriate control like a textbox for strings or a dropdownlist for enum properties.

Does anything like this already exist for ASP.NET, or will I be rolling my own here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ASP.Net PropertyGrid](http://www.codeplex.com/PropertyGrid)

Comment: Which is used... how? Please add more details.